Older movie with a similar premise to Interstellar
There was a movie where humanity is at the edge of extinction, so they send a handful of astronauts into space in solo capsules. They all fly into different directions, but one after another fail and lose contact or die.
At the end of the movie, it turns out that one of the astronauts survived and returned with aliens to Earth only to find that humanity has gone extinct, and also documentation of his mission.

Welcome! It would be useful if you told us when and where you saw the movie - on television, a movie theater, or a dvd. The more context, the more helpful - thank you!

Are you sure it as a movie? I am sure there have been episodes of the Outer Limit or Twilight Zone type TV shows with a similar story.

This is Welcome to Earth (2019), an 18-minute long short film from the Netherlands.

It's 2618 and humans are extinct. Four aliens travel to Earth to visit the museum of humanity. There they find the story of the last heroes of humanity, setting out to find help.

In the year 2087, the Earth is becoming uninhabitable due to climate change. Seven ambassadors are sent on an 'alien outreach' programme in one-person starships carrying 'knowledge probes' (designed to teach aliens English), in the hope that they may be able to return with help. The progress of the ambassadors is monitored from Earth, but one-by-one, each of them suffers some sort of technical mishap resulting in death. The last ambassador, Rene Shepard, crashes and freezes on a icy planet twelve days after departure and it's noted that there's a 10% chance that aliens with the right technology could revive his preserved body.
Centuries later, four cloaked and masked figures arrive on a now completely inhospitable Earth and enter an automated museum which welcomes them and informs them that mankind has gone extinct but invites them to view video records detailing its rise and fall and the alien outreach programme. When the figures unmask, three of them are revealed to be alien while the fourth is Shepard, who was presumably retrieved from the ice and revived by these aliens off-screen, but not in time to save humanity.
That last paragraph is actually the opening scene (with the exception of Shepard unmasking, which happens near the end). We learn the rest of the story from the museum's videos.



